# How to install library on Debian

Tags: c++, c, openssl

I'm learnig security and programming. I'm triyng to use openssl library, I've found some articles and sources on internet, but in no cases I got openssl headers working to use in c/c++.
I searched at debian repositories for dev openssl packages, but no success. Even making the triad config, make, make install with some parameters and copying to /lib folder, the library don't be recognized.

```
HashInterface.cpp:14:10: fatal error: openssl/sha.h: Arquivo ou diretório inexistente
```

14 | #include <openssl/sha.h>
|          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.

Comment: https://serverfault.com/questions/249340/install-openssl-dev-on-ubuntu-server ?

Comment: Welcome to Debian's weird naming conventions. Are you looking for the `libssl-dev` package?